# Orbeon forms editor: "Error at line 32 of oxf:/forms/orbeon/builder/service/toolbox.xsl"

Tags: forms, orbeon

Been successfully using Orbeon 4.4CE for a long time, but today the Form Editor seems to have suddenly broken. Creating a new form (or editing an existing form) shows a partial toolbox missing most of the controls.

Log file reveals this:

`INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/custom/orbeon/builder/toolbox - Received request
ERROR XSLTTransformer  - Error at line 32 of oxf:/forms/orbeon/builder/service/toolbox.xsl:
An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of variable $resources-property
ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  - error caught {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/fr/service/custom/orbeon/builder/toolbox"}`

Configuration is Orbeon 4.4, MySQL persistence layer with MySQL 5.6, Java 1.7.67 and Tomcat 7.0.52 on Ubuntu 14.04. This was working fine as of late last week, and now seems broken on several systems all at once. Nothing in the configuration has changed in several months (as verified by a scan looking for files having recent modification times).

UPDATE: The problem is actually worse than I suspected...I copied an existing, working form from the MySQL orbeon_form_definition table to another Orbeon instance, and the form does not run. The Orbeon log file shows: "An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of variable $captcha" (the form does not use Captcha codes in any way).

We also tried installing a copy of Orbeon 4.7.0CE, and it appears to have similar symptoms.

The same problem is now occurring on three completely independent (but similarly configured) systems - we do not have a way to edit or create new forms using Form Builder, or even to move existing forms around between systems by updating the database definitions.

Any suggestion how to fix this, or even to diagnose where the problem might be?

Comment: It could be that one of the library forms is somehow broken: either `orbeon/library` or `acme/library`, where `acme` stands for your app name. Does it work if you use a different app name when creating your form?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I tried several combinations of app names and form names, and eventually I found one that seems to work. Is there something I can do to figure out what's damaged, or to reset the system to some stable state? As is, I can't even edit an existing form.

Comment: If you are trying to create or edit a for with app/form name `foo/bar`, and it fails, then probably that `foo/library` is damaged or otherwise causing a problem for Orbeon Forms. It might be an Orbeon Forms bug, who knows. If you try to edit the library `foo/library`, does it work? If you have support with Orbeon, can you send us your database?

Answer (score 0):

Today I had a very similar problem.
I created a new form and didn't saw the toolbox controls:  [image: missing toolbox]

Looking in the log there was the following error:

```
 2018-03-16 10:33:26,212 ERROR XSLTTransformer  - Error at line 32 of oxf:/forms/orbeon/builder/service/toolbox.xsl:
 An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of variable $resources-property
2018-03-16 10:33:26,239 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  - error caught     {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/fr/service  /custom/orbeon/builder/toolbox"}
2018-03-16 10:33:26,411 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  -
```

The reason was the name I had chosen for the form: **reset-password**.  I   changed the name in something else and the problem wasn't any more.
It seems that the form name must not contain the string "password".